Zoho Catalyst: How to pull a project from development environment to local machine?
I have a project created in the Zoho Catalyst console. However, I find it difficult to pull the project from the console to my local machine to debug my client and backend application locally.

You can follow the below steps to pull your Catalyst project from development to local machine.
1.Install Catalyst CLI in your local machine. You can find the help documentation for the same here.
2. Create a new folder and initialize the created project in your local machine by running the below command
catalyst init

Select your project and then directly Enter (if you have functions and client created already).
3. Now, a file named catalyst.json and a hidden file named .catalystrc will be created.
4. Now, run the below command and select functions and client as per your requirement to pull the files from the console.
catalyst pull


Now, client and functions folder will be created and the code is pulled in your local machine.
You can run the command catalyst serve to test the application in local and run the command catalyst deploy to deploy the code to the development environment.

